# Magento 2 How to resize product image for email purpose

Tags: magento2

I wrote following code that gets product image displayed on all transactional emails

```
$productId = $_item->getProductId();

$objectManagerHere = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$product = $objectManagerHere->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')- >load($productId);

$store = $objectManagerHere- >get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();

$imageUrl = $store- >getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();

//  displays image
<img height="100" width="100" src="<?= $imageUrl; ?>" alt="<?= __('Product Image');?>">
```

Problem is that these images are too large (kb) for email. Is there any way to resize them using the snippets above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$productImage = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')->init($_product, 'category_page_list', array('height' => '300' , 'width'=> '300'))->getUrl();
echo '<img src="'.$productImage.'" class="small-image" />';
```

in your .phtml file.

Note : Adjust the `width` and `height` properties according to your need.

Comment: This is working solution, only that $_product need to be $product. Thanks Senthil.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$product->getSmallImage()` or `$product->getThumbnail()` instead of `$product->getImage()` 

**NOTE ::** 

It is not recommended to use objectManager directly, recommended way is to use [dependency injection](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply Anshu, this seems to be valid answer. Problem is that from admin i have only one big picture for both small and thumbnail image, and plenty of products with same image config ... So it will always return large pic

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$productId = $_item->getProductId();
$objectManagerHere = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManagerHere->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);


$imageType = "product_thumbnail_image"; // or used => product_small_image
$width =  100;
$height =  100;
$imageUrl =  $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')->init($product, $imageType)
         ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
         ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
         ->keepTransparency(TRUE)
         ->keepFrame(FALSE)
         ->resize($width, $height);


?>
//  displays image
<img src="<?= $imageUrl; ?>" alt="<?= __('Product Image');?>">
```

Comment: Used like this, i am receiving email with error: Error filtering template: Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/Packers/luma/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/invoice/default.phtml on line 35 (img tag).